# How to type an object transformer

Tags: typescript

I have the following object:

```
const schema = {
  student: {id: 'student/student'},
  students: {id: 'student/students'},
} as const;

interface Schema {
    readonly [key: string]: {id: string};
}

type Mapped<V extends Schema, U extends keyof V> = {
    [S in V[U]['id']]: V[U];
}
```

But when I use this type, all the values can be used on every key

```
const a: Mapped<typeof schema, keyof typeof schema> = {
    'student/student': {id: 'student/student'},
    'student/students': {id: 'student/student'},
}
```

Comment: ① `Transformer<typeof {id: 'user/user'}>` isn't valid TypeScript.  Could you please [edit] the question to be a proper [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs without distracting errors you're not asking about? ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mLrPaw) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but please do first edit the code to be a [mre] and not pseudocode); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `Mapped<N>` type you posted? I think it already works as you want. For `Mapped<'users'>` it creates type `{'user/users': Transformer<{ id: 'user/users' }>}`.

Comment: ① You just edited this but you've still got pseudocode `...` and inconsistencies (is it `student` or `user`)?  Could you please try using an IDE to make sure you're not adding distracting issues and then edit again? ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnLGeW) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining (but please first do edit the code to be a [mre]); if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this answered my question. I simplified my question. The solution is to use the type `type Mapped<T extends Schema> = {[K in keyof T as T[K]['id']]: T[K];}`

Comment: Great, I'll write up an answer.  Please [edit] the question to fix the mistakes.

Comment: Okay I've removed the pseudocode myself; if you want to see something else there please replace it with valid code, but hopefully this is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason

```
type Mapped<V extends Schema, U extends keyof V> = {
    [S in V[U]['id']]: V[U];
}
```

doesn't work is because the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `V[U]` is independent of `S`.  You would need to extract the member of `V[U]` corresponding to `S` for that to work:

```
type Mapped<V extends Schema, U extends keyof V> = {
  [S in V[U]['id']]: Extract<V[U], { id: S }>;
}

type M = Mapped<typeof schema, keyof typeof schema>;
/* type M = {
    "student/student": {
        readonly id: "student/student";
    };
    "student/students": {
        readonly id: "student/students";
    };
} */
```

Here I'm using the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter `V[U]` to just the member matching `{id: S}`.

---

An even easier approach is to just iterate over the union members of `V[U]` directly, and [remap](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) the keys to the `id` property of those members:

```
type Mapped<V extends Schema, U extends keyof V> = {
  [W in V[U] as W["id"]]: W;
}

type M = Mapped<typeof schema, keyof typeof schema>;
/* type M = {
    "student/student": {
        readonly id: "student/student";
    };
    "student/students": {
        readonly id: "student/students";
    };
} */
```

So instead of throwing away everything but the `id` property as `S` and then searching back through `V[U]` to find the right union member again, you hold onto the right union member `W` the whole time.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkvAPbBQAuSU8AFhGCEgLx6FHUUCuAJhMBQBceJAEsewgOSVe-CgHoZfAZKQBfADTsiSuVGG4xEpNO7KFugVFWb2apCCjEylANz52ogRABOAMwRkAGU6BiYCDiQfCBAeMgwATyQAbQBrCAThSh8vAHMAXQMjLIoc4Fz1dyI1DyJQSFhApABNNkiKBJhkAFkQGC6eAB4ANSQIAA8Kfh4nEPpGDSQAVTHJ6ad0hJI-JFHWTe3dgD4WNsiUoLFgXeSl-OTJcUl8wqQAUUmfBAoR2-zFwziYSXNRHKocGraJAdLpIbqnXr9CBDGEQQ40eYgRYHHao9GhRhgqHyABU0M6PVOEXORAARJYLGY5LSDFCaURorF4kkgUh6UyBIoBRRaeCaWoxed+bJBQyoCyzuyOJy4sBEsU+QyhTKKPLJZEJVD7CT5LUOKRyFQQMJEQNBnidhiwtiMocHdQCSATqxqZFTDrteZJEVef7zIG5DYtDSw3II1ZgyJQ1qGVGjXYzfVoHBEEgABqK8mw23IkarKbAGZIObO5bl9ZIHG7U5N4bewtEZIAdSuNzujiQXeStPEtJewi7ksh7QpcIRfTt7qdC0brtxFPxmKJkVJRcpPrZHGl4YZCt9SqiMVV6t5x7jp-1EMfdJTwvlrIvyqv3I1d9lb9FQ9qinJATTNIgLUoBwbQXUsl09F0tnXLpNzCdtzyIWN-x1RNAWMLDGRw9Ro3OAj411XCNTI1NiPTaoPDUIA)